# Wildcard when Traversing JSONB Array in Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

We're currently trialing JSONB as a data type for order data in a system we're building. As the document is fairly large, Here is the first part of it (the part that matters):

```
{
"appMessage": {
    "order": {
        "customerSurname": "Tyreus",
        "shipment": {
            "asnNumber": "CC56477332",
            "shippingStore": "3321"
        },
        "orderNumber": "7991218655",
        "propositionCollectionStoreNumber": "5656",
        "collectionPointId": "4",
        "customerFirstname": "Isaac",
        "orderLine": [{
            "collectionWindowFrom": "2017-01-18T09:00:00+00:00",
            "lineNo": "1",
            "skuNo": "7654321",
            "createdDateTime": "2017-01-17T17:54:31+00:00",
```

The issue we're facing is when it comes to applying a wildcard to something in an array. Using the example above, how would I do a wildcard search to say 'retrieve all records with a skuNo starting with 7'?

Outside of an array I have tested wildcards such as:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    ORDERS 
WHERE 
    ORDER_DATA->'appMessage'->'message'->>'enterpriseCode' LIKE 'TU%';
```

With success. But as soon as arrays enter the equation, everything becomes unclear...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can unnest JSONB array using [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and then filter it:

```
--Using 'intermediary' table unnested_json_array
WITH test_data(json_column) AS (

    SELECT 
        jsonb_build_array(
            jsonb_build_object('lineNo', '1', 'skuNo', '7654321'), 
            jsonb_build_object('lineNo', '2', 'skuNo', '1654321'),
            jsonb_build_object('lineNo', '3', 'skuNo', '7654321')           
        )

), unnested_json_array(json_column) AS (    
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements((SELECT * FROM test_data))
) 
SELECT * FROM unnested_json_array WHERE json_column->>'skuNo' ILIKE '7%';

--Or even simpler using LATERAL JOIN   
WITH test_data(json_column) AS (
    SELECT 
        jsonb_build_array(
            jsonb_build_object('lineNo', '1', 'skuNo', '7654321'), 
            jsonb_build_object('lineNo', '2', 'skuNo', '1654321'),
            jsonb_build_object('lineNo', '3', 'skuNo', '7654321')           
        )
) 
SELECT 
    json_elements.* 
FROM 
    test_data 
    JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(test_data.json_column) AS json_elements (order_line) ON TRUE 
WHERE 
    order_line->>'skuNo' ILIKE '7%';

--In your case:
SELECT 
    json_elements.* 
FROM 
    ORDERS 
    JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(ORDER_DATA->'appMessage'->'order'->'orderLine') AS json_elements (order_line) ON TRUE 
WHERE 
    order_line->>'skuNo' LIKE '7%';
```